# how can I hide my discord bot token in python code?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I push my discord bot python project file to my GitHub. I want to share my code without my token. How can I hide my token in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

1. Store your token in a config file. It could be a YAML file, a JSON file, or another python file. And add this config file into `.gitignore` so that git will ignore it.
2. If you want to use git workflow to deploy your bot, you can also choose to store your token as an action secret. Though it will take a bit of work to make the whole thing work. You can read more about Actions Secrets [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your token in your Python code, you can use an [environment variable](https://developer.vonage.com/blog/21/10/01/python-environment-variables-a-primer) instead.

In bash you might run: `export DISCORD_TOKEN="1234"`

And then in your Python code, you can get it with:

```
import os

print(os.environ["DISCORD_TOKEN"])
```

Remember though, that if you now update your code and push a new commit with these changes, someone would still be able to find your Discord token in your old commits.

To fix that, you either need to recreate your git repository from scratch or follow [this guide](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) to remove sensitive commits.

Comment: 3rd option would be to invalidate the old token and create a new one.